# Removing trailing slash from htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make a redirection using htaccess but I run into an issue with trailing slash.

I want to redirect from **https://test.com/transfer** or **https://test.com/transfer/**
to **https://test2.com/destination**
Below is my htaccess rule but it seems to be only working for **https://test.com/transfer** but NOT **https://test.com/transfer/**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/transfer$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://somesite.com/destination/$1 [R,L]
```

What is wrong with my rule?

Comment: @anubhava where do I add "https://somesite.com". This is a different domain from the source domain.

Comment: ok use: `RewriteRule ^transfer/?$ https://somesite.com/destination/ [R,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/transfer/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://somesite.com/destination/$1 [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/transfer/?$ https://somesite.com/destination/ [NC,R,L]
```

Make sure you use `RewriteEngine On` only once.

If you want to redirect everything inside `transfer`: if `transfer` is a dir btw, use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/transfer/?(.+)?$ https://somesite.com/destination/$1 [R, L]
```